# Is there a standard ordering of non-ordinal order types?

Tags: order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Two ordered sets have the same order type if there exists an order isomorphism between them.  The order type of a well-ordered set is called an ordinal number.  There is a standard ordering of the ordinal numbers: if $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered sets, then we say that the order type of $A$ is less than the order type of $B$ if there exists an order isomorphism between $A$ and a proper initial segment of $B$.  And this ordering is in fact a well-ordering.

My question is, is there a standard way to order the order types of all totally ordered sets, well-ordered or not?  Is there at least a standard partial order on the order types of totally ordered sets, even if there isn’t a standard total order?

Comment: Note that those are not partially ordered anymore. Since $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ both embed into one another. So antisymmetry is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are totally ordered sets of order type $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively, then $\alpha\le\beta$ means that $A$ is isomorphic to a subset of $B$. (This agrees with the usual ordering of ordinal numbers if $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered sets.) This relation $\le$ is a *quasi-ordering*: reflexive and transitive but not antisymmetric. The notation $\alpha\lt\beta$ means that $\alpha\le\beta$ while $\beta\not\le\alpha$.

Comment: Is there any class of ordered sets larger than the well-ordered sets for which anti-symmetry holds?  Does anti-symmetry hold for countable total order types excluding order types built out of the order type of the rational numbers?

Comment: Also, can’t we form equivalence classes of order types, where we say that the order type of $A$ is equivalent to the order type of $B$ if they’re both isomorphic to subsets of each other?  And then can we define a partial order on those equivalence classes?

Comment: There are larger classes of ordered sets for which anti-symmetry holds, but I don't know if there are any *interesting* ones. Here's an example showing that anti-symmetry fails for discrete order types. Let $\omega^*$ be the order type of the negative integers. (In general $\alpha^*$ is the reverse of order type $\alpha$.) Let $$\varphi=\omega^*\omega=\omega^*+\omega^*+\omega^*+\cdots.$$ Then $\varphi\le1+\varphi\le\varphi$ although $\varphi\ne1+\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, any quasi-order can be made into a partial order by defining an equivalence relation that way: $a\equiv b\iff a\le b\le a$.

Comment: Oh ok.  And by the way, I know that the cardinality of the set of all countable order types is $2^{\aleph_0}$.  But what is the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes of countable order types under this equivalence relation?  Is it smaller than $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Good question, about the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes of countable order types. I don't know the answer, but probably the set theory experts on this site know it. Why don't you post this as a question.

Comment: "$\alpha\le\beta$ means that $A$ is isomorphic to a subset of $B$". The isomorphism needs to preserve the order, right? So e.g $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, but not vice-versa. If $\omega$ is the order-type of $\mathbb{N}$, $η$ is the order-type of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\theta$ is the order type of $\mathbb{R}$, is it correct to say $\omega\ltη\lt\theta$?

Comment: @Mettek Yes, though I'm used to writing $\lambda$ for the order type of the real line. Of course $\alpha\lt\eta$ holds for any countable ordinal number $\alpha$.